# Change the Title of Panorama Programatically in C# without DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, panorama-control

How can i  change the Tile of Star.xaml(Panorama Activity) Programmatically in WPF using c# 
Like

```
          Panorama.title.text=abc.toString();
```

without using Data Binding
I dont want to make it Complex using DataBinding ..

```
C# code for Second Activity Class            
   namespace Horoscope
{
public partial class Star : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Star()
    {
        InitializeComponent();





    }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string msg = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
        { 
        }



    }
}
```

}

I want to Name the Title by msg from previous activity

Here is Star.xaml

```
                  <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <controls:Panorama Title="my application">

        <!--Panorama item one-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Panorama item two-->
        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
            <Grid/>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
    </controls:Panorama>
</Grid>

<!--Panorama-based applications should not show an ApplicationBar-->
```

Comment: What's the Name of your Panorama control in Xaml? I have never use a panorama control, but I think you can access myPanoramaControl.Title if "myPanoramaControl" is the name of the control.

Comment: Its Star.xaml and Star.xaml.cs 
But there is no title Attribute like Star.Title

Comment: Please provide some code (both xaml and c#) so we can help you.

Comment: Edited Now,There are Two activities ,I want to change it in second one Panorama (Star. xaml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a Name to your panorama control:

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="myPanoramaControl" Title="my application" >
```

and if you need, give a name to panorama items

```
<controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="firstPanoramaItem"  Header="item1">
```

then in code behind set the properties you need:

```
myPanoramaControl.Title = "new title";
```

or

```
firstPanoramaItem.Header = "new header";
```

Hope thi help.